# Phonegap Camera returns photo with black bars

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am using Phonegap 3.4. When I take a photo on iPhone in landscape, I get it back with black bars on top and on bottom.

Here are my camera configuration options:

```
var cameraOptions = {
      correctOrientation: true,
      quality: 90,
      destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: false,
      encodingType: navigator.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 2312,
      targetHeight: 1736,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      popoverOptions: false,
      cameraDirection: navigator.camera.Direction.BACK
    };
```

What should I do to get rid of the black bars?

[image: phonegap camera black bars]

Comment: change correctOrientation to false. Maybe that helps.