# Cordova returns photo in landscape with black region top and bottom

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Is there a way to configure the [Cordova camera plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/) to return photos without the black bands outside of the target height?

E.g., 
[image]

is returned when options set thus:

```
var options = {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        allowEdit: true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 800,
        targetHeight: 1200,
        popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
        correctOrientation: true
      };
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageURI) {});
```

I have tried removing the `targetWidth` and `targHeight` parameters. One issue that you can't know ahead of time whether the photo is landscape or portrait.

This is a dupe of this question that was never answered a year ago: [Phonegap Camera returns photo with black bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641647/phonegap-camera-returns-photo-with-black-bars)

Comment: Is it happening in iOS? As far as i analyzed, in iOS many people have encountered similar issue by not setting launch screen. Check out this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641240/ios-9-xcode-7-application-appears-with-black-bars-on-top-and-bottom

Comment: It has nothing to do with the topic of that link, sorry.

Comment: Could you post your complete code here or in gtihub for us to simulate the issue?

Comment: @metalaureate check with your mobile device camera option there must be some thing you must have selected for this type of view. After invoking the camera go to each and every option in your device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `allowEdit` option or set it to `false`

When you use `allowEdit: true,` it takes you to a crop screen that will create a square image, if you don't zoom the image to crop it, it will add that black regions on top and bottom to make the image a square